# Delete Account that are not associeted with a case

Tags: apex, code

i want to delete all Acccounts in my Org that are not associated with a case in the apex console. How can i do it?

Thanks in avance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the below query in `anonymous window`, which will `delete` all the `Accounts` which are not related to `Cases`.

```
set<Id> accountIds = new set<Id>();
for(Case c : [SELECT Id, AccountId from Case where AccountId !=null]){
    accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
}

delete [select id from Account where Id NOT IN : accountIds];
```

Another approach would be to query on `Account` and get all the `accounts` which does not have any `cases` associated with it

```
List<Account> accountsToDelete = new List<Account>();
for(Account a : [select id, (select Id from Cases) from Account]){
    if(a.Cases.size()==0){
        accountsToDelete.add(a);
    }
}
delete accountsToDelete;
```

---

**UPDATE**

From your comment, you have related `closed/won opportunities`, so you will have to `delete` those `opportunities` first before deleting the `Accounts`, below code should help you

```
List<Account> accountsToDelete = new List<Account>();
List<Opportunity> opportunitesToDelete = new List<Opportunity>();
List<OpportunityHistory__c> opportunityHistoriesToDelete = new List<OpportunityHistory__c>();
for(Account a : [select id, (select Id from Cases),(select id from Opportunities) from Account]){
    if(a.Cases.size()==0){
        accountsToDelete.add(a);
        opportunitesToDelete.addAll(a.Opportunities);
    }
}
opportunityHistoriesToDelete = [SELECT Id from OpportunityHistory__c where OpportunityId__c IN :opportunitesToDelete];

delete opportunityHistoriesToDelete;
delete opportunitesToDelete;
delete accountsToDelete;
```

Note that above two approaches will work only if you have total records (`Account` and `Opportunity`combined) less than `10K` with no `DML` statements on `Account's`/`Opportunity's` `Trigger/Process Builder/Flow`. If you have more than `10K` records which are meeting that criteria you will have to tweak the code and run that tweaked code multiple times.

**Note : It is always advisable to take the backup of the records to be deleted before actually deleting it. You can take the backup of the records using DataLoader or Workbench. Anyhow, deleted records will still be available in the recycle bin for 15 days post deleting it unless it has been cleared.**

Comment: Thank very much @Vijay Ganji but i'm recieving this error:   Line: 7, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 2 with id 0012p00002NQoCCAA1; first error: DELETE_FAILED, Your attempt to delete Cobb132 Inc could not be completed because some opportunities in that account were closed won. The opportunities that could not be deleted are shown below.: Opportunity for Freeman746 : []

Comment: So in that case, you will have to delete the opportunities associated with that account first and then delete the accounts. Updated the answer with the script. That should help you.

Comment: Thanks once more but still have following errors:         System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 2 with id 0062p00000zQzgOAAS; first error: DELETE_FAILED, Your attempt to delete Opportunity for Stokes949 could not be completed because it is associated with the following opportunity histories.: a002p00000pc8cG : []

Comment: I have also tried the second approach but the errors were the same like the first one

Comment: @forzaforza You can run the updated script, this will delete `OpportunityHistory`, `Opportunity` and then `Account`

Comment: yes but still having this error:    DML operation Delete not allowed on List<OpportunityHistory>

Comment: @forzaforza Are you sure, you tried the correct script, Updated script should have worked, I tried it in my dev org and it worked.

Comment: i ran the updated Script and now i'm having the following error:    System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 2 with id 0062p00000zQzgOAAS; first error: DELETE_FAILED, Your attempt to delete Opportunity for Stokes949 could not be completed because it is associated with the following opportunity histories.: a002p00000pc8cG : []

Comment: Looking at the error message, it seems that you have another custom child object of Opportunity called as Opportunity Histories with Id `a002p00000pc8cG`, this is not standard Opportunity History, it is a custom object, can you provide the object's API name, so that it can also be deleted.

Comment: OpportunityHistory__c

Comment: Updated the script, now that should work, I assumed a field called as `Opportunity__c` on `OpportunityHistory__c`, you can replace the field name if it is not the same.

Comment: My field name is OpportunityId__c. i replaced it and i worked. Thanks very Much Vijay Ganji